# can I use Hearing protectors with my earbud headphones for a better listening experience?

Tags: headphones, isolation, earbuds

I was in the process of buying some good quality headphones with excellent Isolation, and I came to the decision to save up some money and buy an expensive one which is something I can't afford atm, however I came across hearing protectors which are affordable and supposed to provide excellent sound Isolation, they are mainly used in shooting ranges, and I thought to myself why not use this on top of my earbuds? my main issue is sound isolation as I mainly listen to music on the bus which is about 2 hours daily, aside for possibly looking like an idiot, is this a good idea and are hearing protectors comfortable to wear?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While having tried those stuff only once - I'm not sure they are really that comfortable.

An usual place one might find them is on construction sites where drilling is required or on a shooting range - perhaps a hardware store might have some on display for testing

Comment: makes sense, I will bring my music and pay them a visit :)

Answer (score 1):

Many professional sound recording crew on big-budget productions use their earbuds with hearing-protectors over the top for critical monitoring in high noise situations.  The COMFORT factor will be more a factor of the earbuds vs. the hearing protectors. Of course there are cheap, uncomfortable hearing protectors just as there are cheap, uncomfortable earbuds.  People who regularly use earbuds professionally often have custom ear-molds made for maximum comfort. There are several YouTube videos about making your own custom earbuds for your ears.